# Upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 resulting in error

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, updates, 20.04

I tried to upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 tp 20.04 using the below command
sudo update-manager -d
I am getting the below error

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This was caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
This is most likely a transient problem, 
please try again later.
If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

Comment: I did sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade before the upgrade to 20.04

Comment: I also deleted the third party PPA's from Other software section in Softwares and updates section.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it might be more than one package, I followed these steps:

1. Check on the file /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log for any broken package listed there
2. Remove the package using apt `sudo apt remove {broken package name}`
3. Run `sudo apt autoremove` to get ride of residual packages
4. Run `sudo do-release-upgrade` again if it throws the error message below:

   Could not calculate the upgrade

   An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

   This was likely caused by:

   - Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
     Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
     package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and
     try the upgrade again.

   If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the
   command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If
   you want to investigate this yourself the log files in
   '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade.
   Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

**Repeat step 1 to 4**