# Errors After Partial upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, updates, ppa

I recently tried to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and the following error occurred.

> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.   This
> was likely caused by:  * Unofficial software packages not  provided by
> Ubuntu Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge  package to
> remove software from a Launchpad PPA and try the upgrade again.

Hence, I tried to resolve this by following the steps mentioned in this link.
[I was unable to update to Ubuntu 20 from Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238620/i-was-unable-to-update-to-ubuntu-20-from-ubuntu-18-04)
The first two answers didn't work for me, then I tried the third answer mentioned, that is by removing all obsolete packages.

The upgrade happened but got a Partial upgrade message and I proceeded with that. It has upgraded to 20.04 but since then, No application is working, Icons are distorted and symbols (close, minimize, wifi, shutdown) are missing, the terminal is not working properly.

What should I do? Is there a way to go back to the factory reset setting or initial setting?

**Note**: Dual Boot on Legion Y530-15ICH.

Following are the errors after resuming the upgrade by **sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**

```
Processing triggers for rygel (0.38.3-1ubuntu1) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:

 libfreeimage3:amd64

 libignition-common:amd64

 libogre-1.9.0v5:amd64

 libfreeimage-dev

 libogre-1.9-dev

 libignition-common-dev:amd64

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. You need to reinstall from scratch it will not work correctly any other way. Make a live media of 20.04 and boot and install from that. If you can save any data you need before the install.

Comment: Try to resume the upgrade by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Post errors to the question body.

Comment: Okay, I tried to resume the upgrade by sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, following are the errors.
Processing triggers for rygel (0.38.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libfreeimage3:amd64
 libignition-common:amd64
 libogre-1.9.0v5:amd64
 libfreeimage-dev
 libogre-1.9-dev
 libignition-common-dev:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

Your output clearly explains why some folks encounter this problem "*Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu*", and indeed your apt output supports that common reason.

The first comment in the [duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238620/i-was-unable-to-update-to-ubuntu-20-from-ubuntu-18-04) clearly explains how to fix it: "*remove all 3rd party software (ie. return to only using Ubuntu repository software), perform the upgrade, reboot then add back any 3rd party software required.*"

Since you didn't do that, and then compounded your mistake with a Partial Upgrade, you are now stuck with a Frankensystem.

It seems clear that your 18.04 version of your non-Ubuntu software is incompatible with Ubuntu 20.04. You must locate a version that is compatible with 20.04

1. You can try following the original advice. It might still work, it might not:

   - Uninstall all non-Ubuntu software
   - dist-upgrade again to eliminate package errors
   - When apt is working properly, install a version of your non-Ubuntu software that is compatible with 20.04
2. Alternately, you can clean-install 20.04, then install a version of your non-Ubuntu software that is compatible with 20.04.

Comment: Thank you for help. Well, I did uninstall 3rd party softwares, also unchecked other software updates, with first error it doesn't proceed to any kind of upgrade and it restores back. Only after uninstalling it initiated the upgradation and after a while prompted to proceed with partial. looks like I missed some. Though, dist-upgrade has fixed icon appearance and terminal, But Yes, clean-installation is the only option to get out of the Frankensystem :)